# OpAmp current source does not work as expected

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, current-source, constant-current

I'm trying to build a constant current source for 2mA ([IEPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Electronics_Piezo-Electric) accelerometer).
The simulation works as expected:

[image: LTspice opamp current source]

But the real circuit is sourcing only about 240µA. Vgs is around 2V; I thought this will work with DMP10H4D2S.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Since you have the simulation working, **measure and compare** all the DC voltages. Which voltages are different?

Comment: The maximum gate-source voltage for the DMP10H4D2S is 20 volts and your circuit is potentially able to exceed that (especially so if you have disconnected the load resistors).

Comment: Is your symbol for the FET meant to show the physical arrangement of the pins? Because normally on SOT-23-3 pin 1 is on the side with 2 pins, so it looks like you have assigned pin numbers differently from the way most manufacturers assign them.

Comment: Even if the symbol is supposed to show the physical arrangement of pins, you've mixed up the source and gate pins, according to the Diodes Inc datasheet.

Comment: The [SPICE](https://www.diodes.com/spice/download/2169/DMP10H4D2S.spice.txt) footprint is different:
10: drain 20: gate 30: source

Comment: I took a new op amp and new fet and tried it with 14V instead of 25V. The 2.5Vref was replaced with 1.25V (due to lack of 2.5V references). This are the measured voltages:
[https://imgur.com/a/jPlKDxi](https://imgur.com/a/jPlKDxi)